# How to delete the text in a whole column

Tags: phpmyadmin

I do have a Table with a column "Modified_Name" and a column with the name "Modified_Time"

As the DB is large, and the tho colums take much space, (and are useless now) I would like to "Empty" those 2 comlums. The data in there became irrelevant for the function of the forum (SMf-forum)

I Searched with PHPMyAdmin but could not solve it from there.
Are Asterix alowwed? Can it work with:

SELECT REPLACE (Modified_Name, '*', ' ')
FROM SMF_Members;

This is a very important Table, so I do not wish to mesh it up. I have made a Backup, but still unsure to go on....

Thanks for the helping hand.

Nicole

What I think I should do